# Android Studio variable cannot be found WebView

Tags: java, android

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.webkit.WebSettings;
    import android.webkit.WebView;

    import static com.example.tencho.cst.R.id.*;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private WebView MywebView;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            MywebView =(WebView)this.findViewById(WebView);
            WebSettings webSettings=MywebView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            MywebView.loadUrl("www.cst.edu.bt");
        }
   }
```

This is the `MainActivity.java`.  it's always giving me an error `cannot find symbol variable WebView`.

I did read the past similar post but I couldn't solve it error.  Please need help!

Answer (score 2):

At this line

> MywebView =(WebView)this.findViewById(id);

id should be like R.id.webview1

> webview1 is the id in your XML layout

Answer (score 1):

The error is on this line:

```
MywebView =(WebView)this.findViewById(WebView);
```

The cause of this error is that the generated `R.id` class has no field named `WebView` (the argument you are passing to the `findViewById()` method). This is probably happening because your layout's `<WebView>` tag is missing an `id` attribute. Add this line to your `<WebView>` tag:

```
android:id="@+id/WebView"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ben's answer is correct. In addition, if your new to Android, if you added this part in your  tag which can be found in your activity_main.xml layout..

```
android:id="@+id/webview"
```

then in your MainActivity.java, it should be like this:

```
MywebView =(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
```